# Converting a GDoc to docx through GAS produces corrupted document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I use the snippet below to convert a Google Doc to PDF and docx format and save it to GDrive. PDF is fine, but docx has problems in Office Word 2013, and doesn't open at all [showing this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rX91.png). LibreOffice 6 can open the file, but only in LibreDraw as read-only, not LibreWriter, and text is in text boxes & borders are plain images, not objects.

If I convert it manually in menu from 
File > Download As.. > Microsoft Word(.docx),
 the document works fine. I have hundreds of files, and doing it manually is not a solution.

```
function saveToDrive(_name){
  //Get document blob for converting
  var blob = DocumentApp.openById('string_id').getBlob();
  //Save as PDF
  var pdf = {
    title: _name + '.pdf',
    mimeType: MimeType.PDF,
    parents:[{id:'google_drive_folder'}]
  };
  Drive.Files.insert(pdf, blob);
  //Save as docx
  var docx = {
    title: _name + '.docx',
    mimeType: MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD,
    parents:[{id:'google_drive_folder'}]
  };
  Drive.Files.insert(docx, blob);  
}
```

I did use string mime type as well, with same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `getBlob()`  by default converts it into PDF. So, When `insert`ing it into Drive as `docx`, you're trying to convert from `pdf` to `docx`.

#### Possible Solutions:

- Use direct conversion from `gdoc` using Drive API `Files:export`
- Directly fetch the export link using `UrlFetchApp`

#### Sample Script:

```
function docToDocx(id) {
  var format = 'docx',
    exportLink =
      'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + id + '/export?format=' + format,
    blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
    });
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

#### References:

- [Files:export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/export)
- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/)
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource))

Comment: How about using [File.getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype) method? Is it possible to make this conversion through that?

Comment: @V.i.K.i In my experience, it almost always fails. I believe it only converts to PDF.