# Appscript save copy as docx

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hey guys i found this guide https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/ on transfering data for sheets to google docs but i am trying to get it to save the files as docx since the files will be sent out to customers.
Is there any easy way to get it to work?

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Oppdrettsbevis');
  menu.addItem('Generer Oppdrettsbevis', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxx');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxx')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[5]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Position}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Hire Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Hourly Wage}}', row[4]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a GDoc to docx through GAS produces corrupted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086648/converting-a-gdoc-to-docx-through-gas-produces-corrupted-document)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if it is possible to *export a .docx*
Try Using, from the crossreferenced post beolw the docToDocx() , which I modified to return the URL.  Edited to include the Entire code with some Logger lines.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

//include this function
function docToDocx(id) {
  var format = 'docx',
    exportLink =
      'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + id + '/export?format=' + format,
    blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
    });
  var thisFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  return thisFile.getUrl()
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xx YOUR TEMPLATE ID HERE xx');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xx YOUR FOLDER ID HERE xx')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[5])
    {
      Logger.log("Document Made already");
      Logger.log(row[5]);
      return;  //Breaks this iteration of the loop should allow next row
    } 
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Position}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Hire Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Hourly Wage}}', row[4]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    Logger.log("The Google Doc: " + doc.getUrl());
    ///Call the docToDocx Function and save the Url: 
    const url = docToDocx( doc.getId() );
    Logger.log("The .docX URL: " + url);
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url);
  }) 
}
```

After Running the Script I can now see in my Execution log:

```
Cloud logs
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:46 PM   Info    The Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/open?id=xx THIS FILE ID xx
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:48 PM   Info    The .docX URL: https://docs.google.com/document/d/xx THIS FILE ID xx_/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=xx THIS TOKEN ID XX&rtpof=true&sd=true
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:50 PM   Info    The Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/open?id=xx THIS FILE ID xx
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:52 PM   Info    The .docX URL: https://docs.google.com/document/d/xx THIS FILE ID xx/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=xx THIS TOKEN ID XX&rtpof=true&sd=true
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:54 PM   Info    The Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/open?id=xx THIS FILE ID xx
Oct 19, 2022, 12:09:56 PM   Info    The .docX URL: https://docs.google.com/document/d/xx THIS FILE ID xx/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=xx THIS TOKEN ID XX&rtpof=true&sd=true
```

That shows the Google docs url is different then the supplied uls that will lead to a download of a .docx file.  Those docx Urls are also showing in column 5 of the spreadsheet.

The docX function was found at theWizEd's commented crossreference:
[Converting a GDoc to docx through GAS produces corrupted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086648/converting-a-gdoc-to-docx-through-gas-produces-corrupted-document)

Comment: still cant get it to work, now it creats the google docs fil but does not add the link or make the docx file

Comment: I got it to work on my end.  I started with the Tutorial, Used the Tutorial Data, Made the modification I showed above,  added a Few Logger lines to trace where the program was.   I have edited the above to include the entirety of my Code.

Comment: the Code will never make the docX file in your folder,  only the google doc.  The Provided url is to export a copy of that google doc as a .docx.